# Change Webbrowser post form before send to server

Tags: c#, php, browser

I want to control web user submits a form in WebBrowser in C#, it means I want when user submited the form, sending data be obstructed , and i make some changes in post data and fields, for example code them with base64 or something like this.

Example:

`<form method=post action=example.php>
<input name=name /><input type=submit /></form>`

example.php
`<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>`

That shows in webbrowser object and when sends to example.php,
it shows exacly enterese data, but I want to encrypt them BEFORE send to web.

Than you.

Answer (score 0):

base64 is not encryption, client side encryption is impossible because the keys/methods are exposed and can be hacked via man in the middle attack.  Pay for an SSL cert, or run your server with a self generated cert.

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle the forms onsubmit event, or even the onclick or onkeydown of the submit button, then inside the event, you need to get access to the form object, like say the form name is form1 and wb is the webbrowser control, do this...

msgbox wb.document.getelementbyname("form1").elements(0).value

this will display the value of the first element in your form, and you can change it that way as well by setting another value to above code like this:

wb.document.getelementbyname("form1").elements(0).value = "new value"

cool? let me know if you have other questions.